# 4G symbol appears but no/slow internet

Tags: samsung, 4g

I have a Samsung Galaxy S21 5G which has worked great, but the last day or so I have been having a very annoying issue where the internet just goes really, really slow, yet it is still showing the 4G symbol in the corner.

Normally, when the internet goes slow, it'll show an 'H', then when it's really bad, an 'E', but while 4G is showing, its usually really quick. Since yesterday, it has been so slow to the point webpages time out, and some apps (such as reddit) fail to load at all (just get an error).

Today, it got more annoying where I actually got a "no connection to internet" appearing on my browser and app store, even though the 4G symbol is showing in the corner.

What I have tried:

- Turning the phone off & on again
- Removing and re-inserting SIM card
- Turning aeroplane mode on/off
- Reset Access Point Names to default (as per online tip)
- Checking Network modes are set correctly

I'm not sure what else I can try. I am using the Virgin mobile network in the UK, which I believe is using the EE network, and their [coverage checker](https://coverage.ee.co.uk/coverage/ee) tells me everything is fine and I should have good coverage.

Is there something I am missing, or anything else I can try as it's rather frustrating. WiFi works fine.

Comment: Couldn't it be a network provider's issue? That would be my guess...

Comment: Possible provider issue: https://istheservicedown.co.uk/status/virgin-media

Comment: @Robert That link times out every time

Comment: Hmm, I can open Robert's link fine. I also noticed Virgin Media mentioned this link to other reporters: https://my.virginmedia.com/faults/service-status

Answer (score 0):

Options you have:

1. Check with other users who are on same network with different mobile.
2. Check with other users who are on same network with same mobile.
3. Get a new SIM card with same number. Yes, SIM cards can cause trouble.
4. If above 4 are checked, then it is the handset problem. Maybe a software factor reset can do a wonder too.